# Change Index value in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am listing a json data in table format.Json contains  different arrays and need to loop these  arrays seperately.Everything working fine except the $index value.

[Working Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/aI992wpMw5pw8oHvGcaj?p=preview)

Here i am looping each array in seperate tr.i need to get the index value updated like 1,2,3..
Any solutions??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you necessarily needs to have them iterated as two different arrays you'll have to add the total number of members in the first array to the indexes for the second array, like this:

```
<!-- second tbody: -->
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="prioritymembers in Records.priorityMembers">
    <td class="no" ng-bind="Records.stdMembers.length + $index+1"></td>
    <td class="name" ng-bind="prioritymembers.members.fname"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/1HiGoMuFAOTyOpD3SLoX?p=preview

Comment: thanks for the reply..but in the case of 3 arrays it wil not work http://plnkr.co/edit/aI992wpMw5pw8oHvGcaj?p=preview

Comment: Got the answer.Just sum up first and second array length Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting proble, I don't think there is a straitforward solution.

You could do

```
<tr ng-repeat="prioritymembers in Records.priorityMembers">
    <td class="no" ng-bind="$index + Records.stdMembers.length + 1"></td>
    ...
</tr>
```

Perhaps the cleaner solution would be to create a single array in the controller and iterate over that, instead of having 2 `<body>`s with separate iterations.

Comment: please check this link http://plnkr.co/edit/aI992wpMw5pw8oHvGcaj?p=preview it will not work for 3 arrays

Comment: Got the answer.Just sum up first and second array length Thanks for the answer.